# Online Screenshot Generator for Mac

Tags: browser, web-development, screenshot

I'm looking for a free online web page screenshot generator that will take photos of Mac browsers.

I've looked at:

- BrowsrCamps
- BrowserShots
- LitmusApp

All of which I'm sure are good but charge for a screenshot of your web app using a Mac browser.

Does anyone know of a free alternative.

Comment: Just pay and stop being stuck-up and stingey.

Comment: @Michael Boyd, way are you down voting this?  I just found a similar post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825599/testing-web-application-on-mac-safari-when-i-dont-own-a-mac but seems to be dated since they all charge now

Comment: superuser.com does not deal with web app questions...

Comment: superuser is for computer hardware and software only. Websites are outside of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Mac have a build in screen shot tool?

`CMD_<SHIFT>_4` should bring up the tool automatically.

Comment: I imagine he doesn't have a Mac and wants to see what a website will look like on it.